# what does "a<?=b" in C++ mean?

Tags: c++, syntax

I saw this code

```
a<?=b; // (a and b are int)
```

from the solution of Google Code Jam.

but my VS shows an error on '?'

I only know the following:

```
a>b?a=0:b=0;
```

Thanks.

Comment: That can't possibly work.

Comment: That does not look like valid c/c++.

Comment: https://code.google.com/codejam/contest/32003/scoreboard?c=32003#vf=1 Please check sclo's answer for problem c 40pt.

Answer (score 9):

Old operator; it's a (since removed) gcc extension for 'minimum'.  That is:

```
a <?= b;
```

is the same as:

```
a = a < b ? a : b;
```

Comment: Wow, I was sure that was not valid

Comment: I guess its not C/c++ valid, but it is gcc valid (or was gcc valid :) )

Comment: @jeremy the question is about c++

Comment: @jeremy: as the OP discovered, compiler extensions may not be valid on other compilers. (A pretty cool operator nevertheless. I'm *sure* I could have used it here or there.)

Comment: For those interested in more: http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Deprecated-Features.html

Comment: Even `--std=gnu++98` doesn't re-enable that extension.

Answer (score 1):

A nonstandard GCC extension to C++ allows `<?` as an operator which is equivalent to `min`. I haven't seen `<?=` before, but presumably it's an in-place version; that is, `a <?= b` is equivalent to `a = min(a,b)`.

Note that the GCC developers woke up the next morning and realized what a bad idea that was. The operator is now deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

If **a** happens to be larger than **b**, it would set a to b.

Essentially the same as:

```
a = a < b ? a : b;
```

Example:

```
int a = 5;
int b = 2;
a<?=b; //a is now 2!
```

I wouldn't advocate actually using such a solution though, it is horrible.

As others have said, it's part of a nonstandard GCC extension, but please don't use it.